# How to tell if a note is sharp or flat if there is no indicator piano

Tags: piano, sheet-music

I'm a Naruto fan and I'm trying to learn this one song called despair on piano but I can't tell where the sharp or the flat is.  On the video it shows where but on the sheet it doesn't which make it really confusing for me here is the link https://musescore.com/user/19985216/scores/5027703
if someone can help ill be really happy pls

Comment: What video? (And perhaps the video you're watching is in a different key than the written arrangement.)

Comment: "indicator" are you not including the key signature? there are no accidentals in the score.

Answer (score 1):

There are no accidentals in the song, however there is there is a sharp on the F note line next to the clef, also called *key signature*. This means that **every** F note in the score, in any octave, is F#.

Below I marked several of those for you:

[image]

Comment: *Technically*, the notes of key signature aren't "accidentals". Accidentals are only the notes altered within the piece with individual sharps/flats/naturals. Thus, in the example, F# isn't an accidental because it is defined by the key signature. However, if somewhere in the piece an F-natural was notated, that one note would be an accidental.

Comment: @InternetChordDatabase Thanks, I tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the "key signature" which is the Sharps or Flats symbols shown at the beginning of each staff between the clef symbol (treble or bass) and the time signature.  In your example, the key signature is 1 Sharp indicating the piece is writing in the key of G Major or E Minor.

Key signatures can be a range of 1 to 7 sharps or 1 to 7 flats (or none of each). Each permutation indicates a different key. There's a lot of theory that goes into them, but to answer your question of which notes are sharped or flatted you have to understand only 2 things.

1. The note-sequence of sharps or flats in all key signatures are always the same.

Sharps: F#, C#, G#, D#, A#, E#, B#

Flats: B-flat, E-flat, A-flat, D-flat, G-flat, C-flat, F-flat

In your example with 1 sharp, that sharp is F#. You can tell this because it is on the F line of both staffs.

2. Any note marked with a sharp/flat in the key signature will *always* be sharped or flatted for the rest of the piece (or until another key signature changes it). The only exception to this rule is when a note in the piece is specifically is notated with an accidental.

So, in your example, *every* F note in will be sharped (not just Fs indicated by the key signature). I don't see any altered Fs in your piece, but an example of that would be a "F-natural" somewhere in the piece where you would play a "F-natural" for that one note.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple in music, there is a statement at the beginning of each line. In your sample, that is a sharp sign on the F line. That means **every** F note in that music must be F♯, unless cancelled by a natural sign, and that will only last for the bar it's in.

In the music shown there are no *accidentals* (♯, ♭, ♮) on *any* notes, so everything is on the white keys - except every F note will be played as F♯.

This piece is in key Em, and uses the natural minor scale notes, as it happens.Just watched a clip and it's in the same key - so the same F♯ each time.